# Are "qui" and "qua" entirely interchangeable?

Tags: grammar

Are "qui" and "qua" entirely interchangeable? If not, could you cite general cases in which they are not?

Comment: Well, when referring to Paperino's nephews, for example =)

Answer (score 15):

They are indeed interchangeable but *qua* is generally seen as less precise in terms of distance than *qui* (see also the comments [here](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/Q/qua_1.shtml) and [here](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/qua2/)), e.g.:

> *Q: Dov'è Mario?
>
>   A1: Boh. È qua.* (meaning: here, in this place or in this building and not somewhere else, not in Alaska, for example)
>   *A2: È qui.* (meaning: right here, in this room, next to me)

However, using either *qua* or *qui* in any of these answers would be perfectly correct.

Note also that only *qua* might be used in combination with adverbs: *quassù, quaggiù*.
I would usually say *Dammi qua* and not *qui* but, as Gabriele has said, this might be a matter of taste.

(Added after some googling: *qua* should never, ever be used in *qui pro quo*. Yes, it has nothing to do with the question, but it seems that some people do believe that the words are interchangeable also in this Latin sentence...).

Comment: +1 Good point about *qui pro quo*. That's not the same *qui* as in Italian, but it's worth noting.

Comment: I don't agree on the difference in precision. In the example you gave I would indifferently use *qua* or *qui* for both sentences.

Comment: @Gabriele True. I would use either of them, too, without much thinking. But the difference in precision is not invented by me; it's an explanation from my elementary school and what dictionaries say: *qua ha molti usi in comune con qui, rispetto al quale può esprimere un'idea di minore puntualizzazione spaziale*. I just demonstrated how such precision might look like, underlining that both words are actually correct in both meanings of "here".

Comment: "Note also that only qua might be used in combination with adverbs"... maybe in *written* or *formal* Italian. When speaking I hear using `quissù` and `quiggiù` quite frequently.

Comment: @Bakuriu You might use them in an informal talk, if you really want to, but they are certainly not common (apart from some locals or regions, maybe). In fact, Dante has used `quissù` in "Commedia," but already in 1744 such usage was considered wrong. See [here](http://books.google.se/books?id=4AhEAAAAcAAJ), page 71, for example.

Answer (score 2):

They are completely interchangeable.

The only reason I can think of for preferring one or the other is they way they sound in specific sentences.

E.g. in the phrase

> Se passi di qua andrai più veloce

I would rather use

> Se passi di qui andrai più veloce

since *andrai* begins with an *a*, and it sounds slightly better to put a word ending with *i* rather than one ending with *a* in front of it.

It's really a matter of taste, though, as both phrases are completely acceptable to say or write.

Answer (score 2):

*Qui* and *qua* are mostly interchangeable, but *qui* has a more punctual meaning whereas *qua* is more vague, similar to the pair *lì* and *là*, *costì* and *costà*.

> **Qui**: exactly here where I am 
>   **Qua**: in my proximity
>
> **Costì**: exactly where you are
>   **Costà**: in your proximity
>
> **Lì**: exactly over there
>   **Là**: around there

In the dictionary of **Devoto-Oli** we have the following definitions

> **qua**<sup>2</sup> avv. (radd. sint.)
>   ~ ‘In questo luogo’: indica vicinanza a chi parla, ma è meno preciso di *qui* (*vieni qua*, vieni nei miei pressi; *vieni qui*, vieni in questo punto preciso)
>
> **qui** avv.
>   ~ Indica vicinanza a chi parla, ma con molta maggiore precisione di *qua* (*qui c’è freddo*, in questo punto preciso c’è freddo; *qua c’è freddo*, nei miei pressi c’è freddo)

That is *qui* is used to refer to a precisely defined point, whereas *qua* lacks this precision, indicating rather an area.

The same in Treccani [qua<sup>2</sup>](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/qua2/) and [qui](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/qui/).

Luca Serianni in his "Grammatica Italiana" writes that

**«Although they are largely equivalent, *lì* and *là* (as *qui*- *qua* and *costì* - *costà*) are not always interchangeable**: *lì* is used (as *qui* and *costì*) preferably for a precise place, defined with precision, while *là* (as *qua* and *costà*) rather indicate a place as an area, without a precise determination. The opposition *location accuray/ areal location*, even if it does not always emerge with clarity, appears evident in congjunction with prepositions. In fact, we will say *di là dal fiume, dal confine*, because we divide the space into areas [...]; *it would not be correct* to say *di lì dal fiume*. Instead, we will say *passare di lì* with exact reference to a precise place [...], which is crossed or touched. In the subdivision of the home space, every room being intuitively an area, we will say vado di là in cucina, vieni di qua in salotto*.

> **Pur essendo per gran parte equivalenti *lì* e *là* (come *qui* - *qua* e *costì* - *costà*) non sono sempre intercambiabili**: *lì* è usato (come *qui* e *costì*) di preferenza per un luogo puntuale, definito con precisione, mentre *là* (come *qua* e *costà*) indica piuttosto un luogo come area, senza una determinazione precisa. L'opposizione *puntualità/arealità*, pur non emergendo sempre con nettezza, appare evidente nelle csotruzioni con preposizione. Diremo infatti *di là dal fiume, dal confine*, perché, così facendo, suddividiamo lo spazio in aree [...]; *non sarebbe corretto* dire *di lì dal fiume*. Diremo invece *passare di lì* con il preciso riferimento ad un luogo puntuale [...], che viene attraversato o sfiorato. Nella suddvisione dello spazio domestico, ogni locale essendo intuitivamente un'area, diremo *vado di là in cucina, vieni di qua in salotto*.

Moreover, we cannot say *in lì, in qui, in costì*.

Outside of books and a part of Tuscany, though, people only use **qui/qua** (here) and **lì/là** (there) with no real difference.